# SQL CASE comparing Text Datarow with Int Datarow

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table, there is the Datarow Comment, which is stored as Text Datatype.

And I have the Datarow idPersonalstamm which is stored as an int.

My Problem is, sometimes it happens that the Data from Personalstamm gets copied in comment.

So I made a case statement which should cast both to varchar and then compare them and if comment equals personalstamm it should set comment as Null if not it should give that comment.

But it always goes to the else statement. What's my fault or how can I achieve my goal in a different way?

The whole thing is part of an Powershell Script which pulls this query once a week from a visitor terminal.

```
> My output looks like this  
> Nr. id. Comment.  
>1---2----2  
> 2---3---some text  
> 3---4---

> it should look like this   
>Nr. id. Comment.   
>1---2---  
>2---3---some text  
>3---4---



<pre><code>SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY vb.Arrival ASC) AS Nr,
       p.idPersonalstamm,
       CASE vr.rating 
          WHEN 3 THEN 'Sehr Gut' 
          WHEN 2 THEN 'Gut' 
          WHEN 1 THEN 'Nicht so Gut' 
          ELSE 'Sonstiges' 
       END AS Bewertung, 
       <b>Case 
          WHEN CAST(vr.Comment as varchar (20)) = CAST(p.idPersonalstamm as varchar (20)) Then null 
          ELSE vr.Comment 
        END as Comment,</b>
       vb.Arrival,
       vb.Departure,
       p.Name,
       p.FirstName,
       p.Company,
       p.Stadt
From Personalstamm p 
  left join (
    select vr.*,
           row_number() over (partition by idPersonalstamm order by idPersonalstamm) as seqnum 
    from VisitRating vr
  ) vr on p.idPersonalstamm =  vr.idPersonalstamm 
  left join (
    select vb.*,
           row_number() over (partition by idVisitor order by idVisitor) as seqnum       
    from VisitorBooking vb
  ) vb on p.idPersonalstamm = vb.idVisitor and vb.seqnum = vr.seqnum
where p.idPersonalstamm is not null</code></pre>
```

Comment: I would use TRIM() to be sure, that vr.Comment does not contain spaces.

Comment: What is your dbms?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you start.)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
Case 
      WHEN LTRIM(CAST(vr.Comment as varchar (20))) = CAST(p.idPersonalstamm as varchar (20)) Then null 
      ELSE vr.Comment 
    END as Comment
```

or:
    Case WHEN CAST(p.idPersonalstamm as varchar (20)) like '%' + CAST(vr.Comment as varchar (20)) + '%' Then null 
          ELSE vr.Comment 
        END as Comment

Comment: Tried it still the same result. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: We must make sure vr.Comment is same with p.idPersonalstamm. Because in some case when the data was inserted by the code it can contain some specific characters. Did you try to copy results to noteopad to compare the lengh of two string?

Comment: posted an example abvoe the code. the langth is simmilar but not viable due to the posibillity that the wanted comments may have also a similar length than idPersonalstamm

Comment: > My output looks like this  
> Nr. id. Comment.  
>1---2----2  
> 2---3---some text  
> 3---4---

> it should look like this   
>Nr. id. Comment.   
>1---2---2  
>2---3---some text  
>3---4---

Comment: What is difference between them? are you expect 1---2--- instead of 1--2--2?

Comment: Yes the scond 2 is the personalstamm data replicated in to the comment filed du to a mistake while login out of the visitor terminal.